# jQuery set text value based on the value of a dropdown and a text value (timepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the set the time in a text field (timepicker) based on the values of a select menu and another timepicker text value.

The idea is that a different appointment types have different appointment lengths, and based on the appointment type and start time, I want to set the appointment end time.

```
<!-- Appt Type --->
<select id="ApptPurpose" name="ApptPurpose" class="form-control">                                   
    <option value="AHA">AHA</option> <!-- 60 minute appointment -->
    <option value="FU">FU</option> <!-- 30 minute appointment -->
    <option value="Screening">Screening</option> <!-- 30 minute appointment -->
</select>

<!-- Appt Start Time--->
<input type="text" name="ApptStartTime" id="ApptStartTime" class="Time form-control" />

<!-- Appt End Time--->
<input type="text" name="ApptEndTime" id="ApptEndTime" class="Time form-control" />
```

I know how to do this in C#, but I was hoping to use jQuery for this. I don't know how to do with the 2 conditions. My jQuery skills aren't very strong.  Here is what I have so far.

```
$(function () {
var ApptPurpose = $('#ApptPurpose').val();
var ApptStartTime = $('#ApptStartTime');
var ApptEndTime = $('#ApptEndTime');

   //when appt purpose changes
   $("#ApptPurpose").change(function () {
      // set end time
   });

   // or when start time changes
   $("#ApptStartTime").change(function () {
       // set end time
   });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is what I have tried so far. I don't think that I am doing the time calculation correctly.

```
$(function () {
var ApptPurpose = $('#ApptPurpose').val();
var ApptStartTime = $('#ApptStartTime');
var ApptEndTime = $('#ApptEndTime');

if (ApptPurpose == "FU") {
   var ApptLength = 30;
}
else if (ApptPurpose == "Screening") {
    var ApptLength = 30;
}
else {
    var ApptLength = 60;
}

//when appt purpose changes
$("#ApptPurpose").change(function () {
    // set end time        

    var StartTime = $('#ApptStartTime').val().split(/:/),
        ApptLengthTime = ApptLength.split(/:/);

    timeDiff(StartTime[0] * 3600 + StartTime[1] * 60, ApptLengthTime[0] * 3600 + ApptLengthTime[1] * 60, $('#ApptEndTime'));
});

// or when start time changes
$("#ApptStartTime").change(function () {
    // set end time
});
```

});

Comment: What you have so far doesn't do anything. Show what you actually tried to implement what you want. We're not here to do it for you, but we'll help you fix it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `.change()` function be on `#ApptStartTime`?

Comment: check this  http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/wg6z8g3L/ . if this is what you wanted i'll post it as answer .

Comment: @JSantosh Wow... you just shamelessly copied my answer hey?

Comment: @stef . do one thing go your fiddle and type some character in that field  and see the result. and do the the same in my fiddle .  i used your code but there is a difference. before saying that `you copied ` see the difference

Comment: Yes I realize you made changes, but a solid 95% of the Javascript is unchanged from my answer. Instead of re-posting my answer as your own, add a comment to my answer with the suggested edits. If it helps the answer I'd happily integrate your edits and give you credit for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with your timeDiff calculation, but I think you're over-thinking the problem.

If you add the duration to the minutes and do a check to see if the sum is equal to or greater than 60, you can simply add an hour and subtract 60 from the minutes' sum to get the proper time. If the sum is less than 60, all you have to do is add the duration to the minutes.

```
function setTime() {
    var ApptPurpose = $('#ApptPurpose').val(),
        ApptStartTime = $('#ApptStartTime').val(),
        ApptEndTime = $('#ApptEndTime'),
        ApptPeriod = ApptStartTime.slice(-2), // Grab the last two characters (am or pm)
        ApptLength = 0;

    // Only proceed if #ApptStartTime isn't empty
    if (ApptStartTime.length) {
        var ApptSplit = ApptStartTime.split(/:/),
            ApptStartHour = parseInt(ApptSplit[0]), // Convert the hour string to an integer
            ApptStartMin = parseInt(ApptSplit[1]); // Convert the minute string to an integer

        if (ApptPurpose == "FU" || ApptPurpose == "Screening") {
            ApptLength = 30;
        } else {
            ApptLength = 60;
        }        

        // Add the duration to the minutes. If it's equal to or more than 60..
        if (ApptStartMin + ApptLength >= 60) {
            ++ApptStartHour; // Increment the hour by 1
            // Fix the hour if it spills over 12 and change the AM/PM to match
            if (ApptStartHour >= 12) {
                ApptStartHour = ApptStartHour === 13 ? 1 : ApptStartHour;
                ApptPeriod = ApptPeriod === 'pm' ? 'am' : 'pm';
            }
            ApptStartMin = ApptStartMin + ApptLength - 60; // Subtract 60 from the sum
            // Make sure we always have two digits (e.g. '00' instead of '0')
            ApptStartMin = ("0" + ApptStartMin).slice(-2);
        // If it's less than 60...
        } else {
            ApptStartMin = ApptStartMin + ApptLength; // Add the duration to the minutes
        }

        // Rebuild the time string and plop it into #ApptEndTime
        $('#ApptEndTime').val(ApptStartHour + ':' + ApptStartMin + ApptPeriod);
    }
}

$('.Time').timepicker({ 'scrollDefault': 'now' });

// When #ApptPurpose changes
$("#ApptPurpose").change(function () {
    setTime();
});

// or when #ApptStartTime changes
$("#ApptStartTime").change(function () {
    setTime();
});
```

**Edit:** Now that we know which timepicker plugin you're using, I've updated my answer to account for AM/PM and to keep it from spitting out erroneous hours like "13:01 PM".

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLgvy7qn/10/

Comment: Thanks you - I struggle working with time.  This taught me a lot!   My start time is formatted with am/pm (I am using the script from here). http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: Nice, that's a pretty elegant timepicker plugin. If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason your dropdown doesn't just have the duration as the value instead of FU, AHA, etc.? You could save yourself a decent chunk of code.

Comment: There is a reason, I need the appt type and because some have duplicate appt lengths, I can't identify the appt type just by length.

Comment: I am having an issue though because the AM / PM is not showing up in the appt end time field.  I have updated the jsfiddle page with what I thought would be a good solution, but it isn't working?  Do you know why?  I can open up another question if need be.  http://jsfiddle.net/uLgvy7qn/7/

Comment: I'm actually working on this as we speak! Just about to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a good shot, but something tells me that I am not doing this in the most efficient manner...

Comment: You were close! But again you're overthinking the logic. We only needed to handle the occasional case of AM / PM switching, everything else worked fine. So instead of handling every possible change, we only had to watch for when the end time gets bumped past 12.

Comment: It it working great now! Thank you!  One question: I have to remove the Time class (comment out //$('#ApptEndTime').timepicker();) from my ApptEndTime input in order to get this to work.  That is OK, but why is that happening?  Is it because I have my time increments set at every 15 on the start time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88122/discussion-between-stef-and-daniela).