# Linking two bootstrap timepicker input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I am trying to implement two dropdown menus: one for a time value, and one for a duration starting from that time onwards. i.e something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGaf2.png).
I am using a bootstrap timepicker for the dropdown menu.
I wrote this method for the first field:

```
$('#timeWithDuration')
    .timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true })  
    .on('change', function() {  
        var from_time = $("input[name='from_time']").val();  
        $('#duration').timepicker({  
            'minTime': from_time,  
            'maxTime': '11:30pm',  
            'showDuration': true  
        });  
    });
```

where `#timeWithDuration` is my first input field and #duration is my second. This works fine the first time I do it (after selecting a value in the first field, I can only see times past that value in the second field) but it then doesn't let me update the values anymore. i.e I can't select a new value for neither the first, nor the second field. The dropdown displays properly, but then doesn't update the value on select.
This is the HTML code for the input fields:

```
<div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input id='timeWithDuration' type='text' class='form-control ui-timepicker-input' name='from_time' placeholder='What time?' autocomplete='off'>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-5'>
    <input id='duration' type='text' class='form-control ui-timepicker-input' placeholder='Duration' autocomplete='off'>
</div>
```

Unexperienced frontend dev here so please be gentle <3 Cheers!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: The code you've written only initializes the `#duration` timepicker. You probably have to use a different method to modify an existing timepicker.

Comment: RejithRKrishnan, I don't have the bootstrap code for the timepicker so can't really do that :-/ sorry.
Barmar, I see. That makes sense now :) I'll try and see what I can do about it

Comment: You can include github code in snippets using [http://rawgit.com/](http://rawgit.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery set text value based on the value of a dropdown and a text value (timepicker)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237193/jquery-set-text-value-based-on-the-value-of-a-dropdown-and-a-text-value-timepic)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [this](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) timepicker.

You will want to create an onchange event on the `#timeWithDuration` input that updates the minTime option on your timepicker.

Also, I would initialize your second timepicker outside of your onchange event for the first.

```js
$('#timeWithDuration')
    .timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true })  
    .on('changeTime', function() {  
        var from_time = $("input[name='from_time']").val();  
        $('#duration').timepicker('option', 'minTime', from_time);
        if ($('#duration').val() && $('#duration').val() < from_time) {
            $('#duration').timepicker('setTime', from_time);
        }
    });

$('#duration').timepicker({'maxTime': '11:30pm', 'showDuration': true});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/master/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/master/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-5">
    <input id="timeWithDuration" type="text" class="form-control ui-timepicker-input" name="from_time" placeholder="What time?" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <input id="duration" type="text" class="form-control ui-timepicker-input" placeholder="Duration" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

As @Shlomi Hassid pointed out in his answer, you would also want to use the timepicker's `changeTime` event, rather than the native `change` event, so that the function will only execute when the input in your `#timeWithDuration` timepicker is a valid time.

Comment: Yeah that looks like what I should be doing. However I'm getting this error:
Cannot set property 'minTime' of undefined. So I'm guessing it's not initialized yet when I'm trying to update it

Comment: Are you still initializing the `#duration` timepicker inside the onchange?

Comment: Added a code snippet to demonstrate. You may need to view it full screen for the bottom timepicker to be visible.

Comment: Also added bootstrap styles to code snippet. And added some code to set the `#duration` time to the same as the `#timeWithDuration` time, if the `#duration` time is less than the `#timeWithDuration` time.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. :) I just realised I'm possibly having more serious problems with my code as I can't update any of the fields regardless. Once a value is set, it will display the dropdown but clicking the other options does nothing. This happens for both fields and independent of each other :-/ I'm a bit confused to be fair

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper event `changeTime` and reset the duration input every time:

DEMO: [**JSnippet**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/297/Bootstrap-Date-and-time-picker-with-linked-duration)

HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
      <input id='timeWithDuration' type='text' class='form-control ui-timepicker-input' name='from_time' placeholder='What time?' autocomplete='off'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-5'>
      <input id='duration' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Duration' autocomplete='off'>
  </div>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var $duration = $('#duration');
  var $timeWithDuration = $('#timeWithDuration');
  $timeWithDuration
    .timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true })  
    .on('changeTime', function() {  
        var from_time = $("input[name='from_time']").val(); 
        if ($duration.hasClass('ui-timepicker-input')) {
            $duration.timepicker('remove');
            $duration.val('');
        }
        $duration.timepicker({  
            'minTime': from_time,  
            'maxTime': '11:30pm',  
            'showDuration': true  
        });  
    });
});
```